# multiple regression advice on results

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, multivariate-analysis, inference

I am testing to see if there is a relationship between my dependent variable Y and any of 4 explanitory variables x1, x2, x3 or x4

First I started by doing simple linear regression and got these results:

```
fit<-lm( Y ~ x1 , data=data)
summary(fit)  # R square .05
fit<-lm( Y ~ x2, data=data)
summary(fit)   # R square -.001
fit<-lm( Y ~  x3 , data=data)
summary(fit)  # R square .01
fit<-lm( Y ~  x4, data=data)
summary(fit)  ###### R square .42
fit<-lm( Y ~  x1+ x2+ x3 + x4, data=data)
summary(fit) ####### R square .46
```

So looking at those results I don't see much. There is an R squared of .42 and .46 when I am regress x4 but it is only .42. I am thinking that there is not relationship here. Am I correct?

I looked into scaling because X1 and X2 are larger in scale but the regression results and R squared values did not change here are the min/max for X1, X2, X3, X4:

```
summary(as.numeric(data$x1) )
summary(as.numeric(data$x2) )
summary(as.numeric(data$x3) )
summary(as.numeric(data$x4) )

> summary(as.numeric(data$x1) )
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   2500  100000  209200  333100  500000 3000000 
> summary(as.numeric(data$x2) )
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
   57440  1146000  2603000  4395000  5142000 47050000 
> summary(as.numeric(data$x3) )
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
  0.01667   0.33330   0.51670   1.52400   1.50000 232.50000 
> summary(as.numeric(data$x4) )
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 -9.187   6.814  16.700  22.920  29.590 177.300
```

I also looked at the residuals of the  fit<-lm( Y ~  x1+ x2+ x3 + x4, data=data) regression to see if the residuals were normal and there are not. I used a qqnorm plot, jarque bera and shapiro wilk:

```
r<-resid(fit)
plot(r)
qqnorm(r) # residual does not look normal there are huge diviations in the tails
qqline(r)
jarque.bera.test(r) #pvalue < .05 so residual is not normal
shapiro.test(r) #pvalue <.05 so residual is not normal
```

Since the residuals are not normal I am concluding that fit<-lm( Y ~  x1+ x2+ x3 + x4, data=data) is not a good model.  Is that correct?

here is a plot of the data

[image]

here is plot(fit)
[image]

I am new to multivariable regression and was wondering if you could advise me what if anything I could/should do next to determine is there is a relationship. Are there other strategies I should look at to see if there is a relationship.

Thank you for your time.  Here are the actual regression results:

```
> fit<-lm( Y ~ x1 , data=data)
> summary(fit)

Call:
lm(formula = Y ~ x1, data = data)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-32.080  -9.428  -3.143   4.303 123.535 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 1.007e+01  9.560e-01  10.532  < 2e-16 ***
x1          1.144e-05  1.965e-06   5.821 9.93e-09 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 16.4 on 552 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.05783,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.05613 
F-statistic: 33.88 on 1 and 552 DF,  p-value: 9.926e-09

> fit<-lm( Y ~ x2, data=data)
> summary(fit)

Call:
lm(formula = Y ~ x2, data = data)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-30.630 -10.064  -3.525   4.662 131.045 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 1.354e+01  8.921e-01  15.181   <2e-16 ***
x2          7.634e-08  1.206e-07   0.633    0.527    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 16.89 on 552 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.000725,  Adjusted R-squared:  -0.001085 
F-statistic: 0.4005 on 1 and 552 DF,  p-value: 0.5271

> fit<-lm( Y ~  x3 , data=data)
> summary(fit)

Call:
lm(formula = Y ~ x3, data = data)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-29.660 -10.207  -3.195   4.666 130.886 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 13.59186    0.72132  18.843  < 2e-16 ***
x3           0.18843    0.07093   2.657  0.00812 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 16.79 on 552 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.01262,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.01084 
F-statistic: 7.058 on 1 and 552 DF,  p-value: 0.008122

> fit<-lm( Y ~  x4, data=data)
> summary(fit)

Call:
lm(formula = Y ~ x4, data = data)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-69.302  -4.355  -0.970   4.667  81.136 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  3.94034    0.73664   5.349  1.3e-07 ***
x4           0.43353    0.02159  20.081  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 12.84 on 552 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.4221,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.4211 
F-statistic: 403.2 on 1 and 552 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

> fit<-lm( Y ~  x1+ x2+ x3 + x4, data=data)
> summary(fit)

Call:
lm(formula = Y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4, data = data)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-63.697  -4.918  -0.487   4.119  76.460 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  1.744e+00  8.672e-01   2.012  0.04476 *  
x1           9.994e-06  1.625e-06   6.150 1.49e-09 ***
x2          -2.351e-07  9.639e-08  -2.439  0.01505 *  
x3           1.552e-01  5.236e-02   2.964  0.00317 ** 
x4           4.189e-01  2.094e-02  20.007  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 12.37 on 549 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.4665,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.4627 
F-statistic:   120 on 4 and 549 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Comment: Can you add a plot of fitted values versus residuals? I think you may have heterocedasticity in your models.

Comment: @Aghila - I have added the plot(fit). Can you provide your interpretation?

Answer (score 3):

For a start - visualize your data !
Try

```
pairs(your_data)
```

For a nicer plot install GGally package and use

```
ggpairs(your_data)
```

If you post your plots here, I will try to help further.

For x3 you have 3(either 3 or many overlapping points) outliers. Are those large x3 values meaningful? Either exclude points as outliers or at least try to use log(1+x3) instead of x3. For x4 there is definitely a correlation, the picture is "spoiled" by zero y at large x4. Ask yourself - can it be that those instances can be "excluded" or "marked" by another variable or a combination of variables? x1 and x2 individually seem to be uncorrelated with y.

I think, you should try to include the interactions between variables in your model.

If you want to stick to linear model, try

```
lm(y ~ .*.)
```

for a two-way interactions or

```
lm(y ~ .^3)
```

for a 3-way interactions or, if you want to "automatically" exclude non-relevant variables

```
step(lm(y ~ .*.), direction="backward")
```

Read the documentation for the "step" function, you may want to use trace=1 to see step-by-step elimination of non-relevant variables.

Another approach would be to use something beyond the linear model. Since your purpose is understanding, try decision trees. They are easy to visualize and interpret.

Comment: I have added the ggpairs plot. Thank you for looking.

Answer (score 1):

As lanenok points out, for x3 you have some extreme values. This values will have a high leverage in your model and should be handled accordingly.

Looking at your diagnostic plots, there's a lot of things that seem wrong in your model. The heterocedasticity is clear, with higher fitted values having higher variance. This yields your p-values wrong, since they are calculated assuming homocedasticity. You have also some observations which are clearly having a great influence in the model (Residuals vs. leverage plot). Those x3 extreme values seem to be the culprit here, but there could be more. A possible solution has been already suggested by lanenok which is log-transformation of x3. Robust regression would be another option.

To solve the heterocedasticity problem, you could perform generalized least squares, which allows for heterocedasticity as long as you specify the variance structure of your model. (see the *gls()* function in *nlme* package)

I would avoid fitting the 3-way interactions and then using step to "automatically" exclude non-relevant variables. Stepwise will yield missleading results regarding your "relevant" variables, their estimated coefficients and their p-values. See this post: [Algorithms for automatic model selection](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20836/algorithms-for-automatic-model-selection)